# openURL tel-scheme iPhone

Tags: iphone

When I try to dial a telephone number(using openURL method of UIApplication class) with e.g. +47 00 00 00 00 it does not work, however when I change to +4700000000 it works.

I don't need an example of how to convert from the first example to the last, but is there any methods that does this conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *withSpaces = @"+47 00 00 00 00";
NSString *withoutSpaces = [withSpaces 
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                           withString:@""];
```