# Codename One App not dialing phone number on iOS device

Tags: codenameone

**Display.getInstance().dial(String number);** is doing absolutely nothing in my iOS app. Works fine at Android and displays a messagebox in the simulator. What have I done wrong for iOS?
Phone number is somthing like this: "+43 664 12345678" (plus sign, country code, net code, number).

Built with Codename One 7.0.108, tested with iOS 16.5.1 on a iPhone 14 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742177/openurl-tel-scheme-iphone?rq=3). The spaces aren't supported by the Apple URL format, you need a number without the spaces, dashes etc.

Comment: Oh, it's true. Phone numbers without spaces are accepted by iOS. But it's a pity that iOS inserts spaces afterwards, on positions we don't like.